# How to Combine the Sort, Filter and IFS Formula for Assigning Unique Id

Tags: sorting, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, uniqueidentifier

**Please help me write the correct formula in Google Sheets to achieve the following goal:**

I want to sort data found in specific rows within a column, and then, depending on the order they are sorted in, assign a Unique ID to that row plus the 3 rows that follow. This results in a group of 4 rows that are sorted together. The specific rows to sort are 2, 6, 10, 14, 18, 22 (every 4th row). Formula in question will be in cell B2. Please note, we are NOT sorting by the Unique IDs as they are written. Rather, we are assigning a Unique Id depending on the sorted Data.

**I have attempted formulas from these tutorials, with no success?**

- https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/query-with-importrange-in-google-sheets/
  https://www.spreadsheetclass.com/google-sheets-sort-filter-functions/
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qo9FbK_rnhE
  https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-not-equal-to-greater-than-less-than/comment-page-3/

**Overall Structure:**

Col A = Sort Key (this probably does not need to be addressed here)

Col B = Unique IDs

Col C = Labels

Col D = Data

**Example:**

**Column B**

ID 1

ID 1

ID 1

ID 1

ID 2

ID 2

ID 2

ID 2

ID 3

ID 3

ID 3

ID 3

**Column C**

*(the following letters, such as "1A" refer to labels, not cells. Specifically - "Label 1A" is actually "Time 1" and "Label 2B" is actually "Event 2", but I am trying to reduce these to the minimum viable example requirements):*

Label 1A

Label 1B

Label 1C

Label 1D

Label 2A

Label 2B

Label 2C

Label 2D

Label 3A

Label 3B

Label 3C

Label 3D

**Column D**

5 (numerical value)

string (of text)

string

string

4

string

string

string

1

string

string

string

---

If properly sorted, this should be the result (NOTE: I've added more specific examples): [Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KPiBlaGWS_KLnUSBoXvxa1rP4Do1Kfo2Csm920kc4s0/edit?usp=sharing)

***Another Edit:
Please note - The Unique Identifiers are NOT unsorted. They simply cannot be assigned at all until the data is sorted, so Column B is all formulas ***

Comment: based on what are columns C & D sorted?

Comment: The sorting factor should be the numbers (5, 4, 1) shown in Column D.  Their row labels (Column C) should migrate together with them after sorting.

Comment: answer updated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your insufficient example...

```
=INDEX("ID "&SORT(ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(C4:C))/4), 1, ))
```

[image]

---

### update 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"ID "&ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(C4:C))/4), 
 QUERY(SORT(C4:D, IF(D4:D="",, VLOOKUP(ROW(D4:D), 
 IF(ISNUMBER(D4:D), {ROW(D4:D), D4:D}), 2, 1)), 1), 
 "where Col1 is not null", )})
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EzekIpg42U6BCQoN7sJck2evFTwwXn20lYBYxb2OQE8/edit#gid=0)

---

### update 2:

```
={"id"; ArrayFormula(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(VLOOKUP(ROW(D2:D25), 
 SORT({SORT(FILTER({ROW(D2:D25), D2:D25}, ISNUMBER(D2:D25)), 2, 1), 
 "ID "&SEQUENCE(ROWS(FILTER(D2:D25, ISNUMBER(D2:D25))))}), 3, 1), 
 ROWS(FILTER(D2:D25, ISNUMBER(D2:D25)))*4, 1))}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I provide you with a better example? People usually complain that my examples are not the "minimum reproducible example." I'm happy to provide something closer to my real usage case with actual data examples in it. For now, I'm trying out the formula you provided. It is not working yet, but that's probably up to me to translate it.